# Is there a slide/negative reader with TV output?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, presentation, slides

Is there a way to display slides directly on TV? I'm looking for something like Kodak Carousel but digital with TV output.

Comment: Nothing shows up on a search, but then the slide viewer market isn't exploding either... You could cobble one yourself- take a Carousel, remove the lens, put a lower wattage bulb in, place a suitable camera with a macro/micro lens and HDMI output in front of the projector facing the slide to be viewed. Plug everything in and Bob's your Uncle!

Comment: Do you literally mean connecting an ancient Carousel ring to a TV? Or do you mean you want to make a nice slide show on your TV? What kind of TV do you want to connect to? If its an old, CRT type, the images don't have to be very good since they are such low resolution devices. If you mean a modern HDTV with HDMI input, all you need to drive it is an HDMI cable to connect to your computer or even to a computer tablet.

Comment: wow, that sounds like a big workaround :)

Comment: For @BobT's solution, you'd also have to put the slides in the carousel backwards.  The only better workaround I can think of is throwing a thick, white sheet over your TV and projecting the slides onto that.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

With your DSLR plugged into your TV, you could put a [dupliscope](http://www.max.grenkowitz.net/?topic=1114) on the front of it. A quick search on eBay showed me several for less than $100.